# server doesn't read request without mime-type

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

I'm having issue reading the contents of the request body at the server end. Apparently the server only reads files which have a content type. Like if the client sends the request with the header :

```
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}",
                    "myFileDescription",
                    "A sample file description"
```

It won't be read at the server side, but if the header looks like this:

```
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";"
         + "filename=\"temp.txt\"\r\n"
         // Add the file's mime-type
         + "Content-type: plain/text\r\n\r\n"
```

then the server will read the contents of this header. I have no idea what is causing this issue, I have created several threads on this issue but no one has given me any answer.

My server side code looks like this:

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;


        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {

                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                // NOTE: To store in memory use postedFile.InputStream
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

and my client code looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest requestToServer = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);

        // Define a boundary string
        string boundaryString = "----";

        // Turn off the buffering of data to be written, to prevent
        // OutOfMemoryException when sending data
        requestToServer.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        // Specify that request is a HTTP post
        requestToServer.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        // Specify that the content type is a multipart request
        requestToServer.ContentType
            = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
        // Turn off keep alive
        requestToServer.KeepAlive = false;


        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string boundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "\r\n";
        byte[] boundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(boundaryStringLine);

        string lastBoundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "--\r\n";
        byte[] lastBoundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(lastBoundaryStringLine);

        // Get the byte array of the myFileDescription content disposition
        string myFileDescriptionContentDisposition =string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}",
                    "myFileDescription",
                    "A sample file description");
        byte[] myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes
            = ascii.GetBytes(myFileDescriptionContentDisposition);

        string fileUrl = file;
        // Get the byte array of the string part of the myFile content
        // disposition
        string myFileContentDisposition = string.Format(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"{0}\"; "
             + "filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
            "myFile", Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), Path.GetExtension(fileUrl));
        byte[] myFileContentDispositionBytes =
            ascii.GetBytes(myFileContentDisposition);


        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUrl);

        // Calculate the total size of the HTTP request
        long totalRequestBodySize = boundaryStringLineBytes.Length * 2
            + lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length
            + myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length
            + myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length
            + fileInfo.Length;
        // And indicate the value as the HTTP request content length
        requestToServer.ContentLength = totalRequestBodySize;


        // Write the http request body directly to the server
        using (Stream s = requestToServer.GetRequestStreamWithTimeout(1000000))
        {
            // Send the file description content disposition over to the server
            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes, 0,
                myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length);

            // Send the file content disposition over to the server
            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileContentDispositionBytes, 0,
                myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length);

            // Send the file binaries over to the server, in 1024 bytes chunk
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } // end while

            fileStream.Close();

            // Send the last part of the HTTP request body
            s.Write(lastBoundaryStringLineBytes, 0, lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length);

            WebResponse response = requestToServer.GetResponseWithTimeout(1000000);

            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string replyFromServer = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            return replyFromServer;
```

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in the server code to try stepping through its execution? Can you determine where the problem occurs? Are any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: And I think you need to have the filename and other header information there for the server itself to know how to handle the file being sent.

Comment: httpRequest.Files contains the keys for the header contents. If the correct header comes through then it's shown in httpRequest.Files. I have set up break points to see the file contents and the file count shows the number of files contained in the request. Is is it necessary to have the file name? what other header information? I followed a tutorial which has the header sent to the server as in my code above

Comment: What should the header look like if I'm not sending the file, just the data? and how will it be processed at the server end?

Comment: I think I may have figured out the issue. The server is trying to look for file where as the first header doesn't contain any file. How can I read the data contained in the string on the server?

Comment: that was indeed the problem. I'm trying to look for form contents where as the server is reading file contents.

Answer (score 0):

This was a casual mistake on my part. My server side code only reads File contents where as my header contains both file and form contents. The file contents will require a Mime type to be processed at the server. The form data doesn't need a mime type and is contained inside `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.